# Social sharing meta tags display by SPA Angular hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, single-page-application

I have SPA AngularJS app hosted on IIS. The problem is displaying meta tag generated by ngMeta (https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta). I don't have any server side app (only ASP.NET web API which provides data). Is any possibility to make my site 'Social Friendly' without any server-side prerendering?

Now it look likes as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywL7p.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set fallback, static HTML meta tags that are removed when Angular is available (using `ng-if`).

```
<title ng-bind="ngMeta.title">Fallback title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Fallback description" ng-if="false" />
<meta name="description" content="{{ ngMeta.description }}" />
```

Social media crawlers generally don't execute Javascript, so they would see `Fallback description`, while Google's Javascript-enabled crawler would pick up the description set by `ngMeta.description`.

Note that the above code provides a site-wide title, description and other meta tags. If you'd like to customize the meta tag values according to the route, you can do something like this

1. Identify user-agent of request to server
2. If user-agent matches a known [social media crawler's user agent](https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents/blob/master/crawler-user-agents.json) string, redirect to a script instead of serving the file.
3. Check the requested route (for example, `/blog`) and return or generate an HTML page with the meta tags relevant to the blog page.